# string formatting in Html

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a template in HTML

```
{% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
        {% for i in quantities %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                <td id="q1">{{ i }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```

How can I assign a different id to each item in quantities?
Can I use .format just like we do in python?

Comment: What do you mean by `each item`? `td`'s `id` attribute? Which id do you want to assign? Product id? quantity number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
    {% for i in quantities %}
        <td id="q{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: There are 5 items in quantities, so I want to assign q1 to the first, q2 for the second and so on

Comment: @YantraLogistics updated answer according to new details